# How to get fields from parent object model in serializer - django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models.. The Discussion extend GenericModel.

```
class GenericModel(models.Model):

content_type = models.ForeignKey(
    ContentType,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
)

object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()

content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

**And**

```
class Discussion(GenericModel):

author = models.ForeignKey(
    'auth.User'
)

name = models.CharField(
    max_length=200
)

description = models.TextField()

created_data = models.DateTimeField(
    default=timezone.now
)

comments = models.ManyToManyField(
    'discussions.Comment',
    default='',
    blank=True,
    related_name='discussion_comments'
)

is_closed = models.BooleanField(
    default=False
)

visits = models.IntegerField(
    default=0
)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

**And**

```
COMMON_FIELDS = (
'pk',
'author',
'name',
'description',
'created_data',
'comments',
'is_closed',
'visits'
)


class DiscussionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Discussion
    fields = COMMON_FIELDS


class DiscussionListSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
comments = CommentSerializer(many=True)

class Meta:
    model = Discussion
    fields = COMMON_FIELDS
```

So.. if I put 'content_type', 'object_id', 'content_object' on the COMMON_FIELDS list, the application return me this errors:

```
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "contenttype-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

How can I do this, or what is the better way for resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` and your serializer will try to resolve the URL for the related `GenericModel` on your `Discussion`.

I believe a solution would be to define the `GenericModel` field on your `DiscussionSerializer/DiscussionListSerializer` to use it (Also defining a `GenericModel` serializer). It would be better than trying to resolve the URL for something that wasn't included on the model. See the serializer [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects) on dealing with nested objects for that.